# How to start the 'Scheduled Task Wizard' in C#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to start the 'Scheduled Task Wizard' from the click of a button in my C# project. Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Note: I am not interested in creating/starting or stopping a task programatically, I just want to start the wizard and/or the Scheduled Tasks folder and/or both.

I apologize if this has been answered before but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you mean `%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc /s` or the wizards it contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28VS.71%29.aspx) method to kick off the following command:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc /s
```

Comment: Keep in mind this doesn't work on every system. On my XP SP3 computer it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, this works on Windows 7 but not on our systems at work. Which is where I need it.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is `control schedtasks`, but it won't open the actual wizard, just the scheduled tasks list.

Comment: Thanks, this will do the job for now.